# Web2Py Multiple Smartgrids in a view

Tags: python, web2py

I am trying to build a view in web2py that has multiple smartgrid objects served from the same controller.  It displays them absolutely fine, but whenever I try to create a new record on the second table it doesn't allow entry, it just seems to refresh the page.  Also trying to search on the second table actually fills in the search field on the first table too, so there is obviously some confusion as to which smartgrid is which.

In my research I came across the multiple form technique using process to name each form, see below:

```
form1.process(formname='form1')
```

However, this methodology doesn't seem to work for smartgrid objects (as far as I can tell).   I guess I could try to create my own new SQLFORM.grid, but it seems a shame that I can't make better use of the smartgrids, as they have everything I need already.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: After further research it seems that you cannot have multiple grids in the same view, so the way around it, that I have used, is placing each smart grid into a separate view and then utilising iFrames to bring them all into one view.  This isn't ideal and becomes a bit fiddly but ultimately gives you the functionality required.

Comment: A solution with two LOAD(..., ajax=True ) require also setting unique formname for grids, like this ```return dict(record = SQLFORM.grid(q_record, formname='records'))```. Else 'Back' button of the first grid during 1 record view will be link to the second grid.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted, you cannot have two grids on the same page in this manner, as the grid makes use of the URL to determine its current state. Instead of the iframe approach, though, you might consider putting each grid in an Ajax component. In the main view file:

```
{{=LOAD('default', 'grid1.load', ajax=True)}}
{{=LOAD('default', 'grid2.load', ajax=True)}}
```

Of course, you can also serve both grids from the same action by specifying a URL arg to differentiate them.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the grid machinery to deal with generated URLs like

`/app/default/grid1.load/view/record/1?_signature=88ce76119afc68bbb141fce098cbc2eaf39289e3`

for a view of a single record, 
you must identify grids uniquely.
So construct your grids with `formname` keyword. Example:

```
def manage_records():
    q_record = (db.record.au==auth.user_id)
    return dict(record = SQLFORM.grid(q_record, formname='records'))

def manage_reports():
    q_report = (db.report.au==auth.user_id)
    return dict(record = SQLFORM.grid(q_report, formname='reports'))
```

Just as Antony have pointed, you can use LOAD() functionality.
You can omit ajax=True, if you want forms will load with a main page.
In the view with two grids:

```
<h2>Reports</h2>
{{=LOAD('default', 'manage_reports.load')}}

<h2>Records</h2>
{{=LOAD('default', 'manage_records.load')}}
```